# What API should I use for speech to text recognition?

Tags: javascript, api, speech-recognition

I need to create a chrome extension in which I will use voice recognition - speech to text. The application should only recognize numbers, I don't care about the rest. If I say a number, it should write it down immediately (without any delay) in digit format. The application should work continuously from manually launch to manually stop

Could you please advise me which API to use, ideally not too expensive for this project? Expectations: There is maximum of 100 people per day/2 hours. For every minute 5 numbers should be recognized

I tried to use the WebSpeech API, but it has a limit of 5 minutes from the start of the recognition. Also, transcription from speech to text is not real time as I wished it would be.